# TreeView Node field size limitations

Tags: winforms, treeview

I'm working with a C# TreeViewControl that's been customized and locked. The problem I'm having is that one of the fields in the node has to be able to handle up to 8k of chars.  However, if I expand the field so that it contains more than 5.4k ALL of the data in that field simply disappears from the screen.  Is there a size limit that I can override somewhere?  Or even a way to wordwrap that field?

Thanks.

Comment: 8k chars? in a treeview? The strange is it did not exploded... What I would do in your case is to represent on the tree the most basic data and when the user selects a node present a detail interface with the complete node's data.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm angling for.  However, I haven't been able to find the handle so that when I click on a node I can do... well... anything.  I'd like to just popup a box that has the data in it.

Comment: The base TreeView can only display up to 259 characters, so most likely this custom control has `DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText`.  If the control overrides the 'OnDrawNode' method, there is not much you can do to replace its logic.  If it internally subscribes to the `DrawNode` event, then you could use Reflection to reroute that to a new handler.  Does this custom control provide any other additional features that are used?  If not, use a standard TV and do as @Gusman suggested.  You could also or use Reflection to set to `DrawMode=Normal` and provide your own display mechanism.